# I have an Stackoverflow error, Stack codes here

Tags: vb.net, stack-overflow

```
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 508   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 942   Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.gir() Line 1693 Basic
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.btnBaslat_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 1673    Basic
[External Code]
```

I upload 120-130 video then gives stackoverflow error and stopped work.
How to fix this problem? Why gives stack error?

```
Dim ru = New ResumableUploader(1)
RemoveHandler ru.AsyncOperationProgress, AddressOf ru_AsyncOperationProgress
RemoveHandler ru.AsyncOperationCompleted, AddressOf ru_AsyncOperationCompleted
AddHandler ru.AsyncOperationProgress, AddressOf ru_AsyncOperationProgress
AddHandler ru.AsyncOperationCompleted, AddressOf ru_AsyncOperationCompleted
Dim youTubeAuthenticator = New ClientLoginAuthenticator("app", ServiceNames.YouTube, username, password)
youTubeAuthenticator.DeveloperKey = devkey
Dim newvideo = New Video()

'  ru_AsyncOperationCompleted sub

Dim settings = New YouTubeRequestSettings("app", devkey, username, password)
Dim request = New YouTubeRequest(settings)
Dim v As Video = request.ParseVideo(e.ResponseStream)

If Not v Is Nothing Then
    'DB Insert
End if
settings = Nothing
request = Nothing
v = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right at the bottom of that, you can see that you've got a repeating set of function calls:

```
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic 
[External Code] 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.upload() Line 895 Basic 
uploader.exe!uploader.Form1.ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(Object sender, Google.GData.Client.AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e) Line 1143 Basic 
[External Code]
```

So, that tells you that `ru_AsyncOperationCompleted` calls `upload` which calls `ru_AsyncOperationCompleted`, which is why your stack is overflowing.

Comment: But this gives me upload succeed info. how to solve this problem? i am new to .NET Thanks for help

Comment: How to use invoke method this?

Comment: Just need to change your upload complete handler to not upload something else (instead get what started the upload to queue them all)